# How I can send additional header when configuring RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: masstransit

I want to use Single Active Consumer feature of RabbitMQ as described here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#single-active-consumer.

> Single active consumer can be enabled when declaring a queue, with the x-single-active-consumer argument set to true, e.g. with the Java client:

```
Channel ch = ...;
Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<String, Object>();
arguments.put("x-single-active-consumer", true);
ch.queueDeclare("my-queue", false, false, false, arguments);
```

I couldn't find a way to add custom header at the moment of queue declaration.
I am configuring my endpoints like this:

```cs
busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, rabbitConfig) =>
{
    // ...

    rabbitConfig.ReceiveEndpoint(endpointName, (IReceiveEndpointConfigurator a) =>
    {
        a.ConfigureConsumer(context, consumerType);

        // a.ConfigureSend(...)
        // a.ConfigureReceive(...)
    });
});
```

With `ConfigureSend` and `ConfigureReceive` I can add/read headers to the message, but I need to add x-single-active-consumer when queue is created in rabbit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I was casting endpoint configurator to IReceiveEndpointConfigurator, while it should be IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator (which is default type)

Correct code:

```cs
busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, rabbitConfig) =>
{
    // ...

    rabbitConfig.ReceiveEndpoint(endpointName, (a) =>
    {
        a.SingleActiveConsumer = true;
        a.ConfigureConsumer(context, consumerType);
    });
});
```